# SVG Path Fill property not working as it should

Tags: svg, path, fill

please have a look at this code and let me know where I'm going wrong, the fill property does not appear to be working? This is supposed to mimic a car turn signal.

I have checked and it appears this is the correct use of the fill property but it is not working as expected. Also I have tried with a much simple path such as a triangle and this worked - so what is unique about this shape if path = path?

```js
function trafficLighttoggle() {
    var pth = document.getElementById("pth");

    if (pth.classList == "traffic") {
        pth.classList = "white";
    } else {
        pth.classList = "traffic";
    }
}

setInterval(trafficLighttoggle, 500);
```

```css
.traffic {
    stroke: #ffbf00;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: #ffbf00;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.white {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: white;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg overflow="visible">
    <path id="pth" class="traffic" d="M160,90 L210,50 M210,50 V70 M210,70 H290 M290,70 V120 M290,120 H210 M210,120 V140 M210,140 L160,90 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is wrong with my code, I got my path generator incorrect it should have been

```
<path id="pth" class="traffic" d="M160,90 L210,50 V70 H290 V120 H210 V140 Z"/>
```

So this is now resolved.

Thanks.